# xcode 4.3.2 core data, where to set delete rules

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-data

I cannot for the life of me find where to set the delete rules for Core Data in Xcode 4.3.2
Not in file inspector, not in Core Data Model inspector, nor when I click anything, like the entities, relationships, et al. And believe me, I have clicked everything I could see. Please Help. 
Where and How do I set the delete rules. I want to set it to Cascade...
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your relationship and select the "Data Model Inspector" tab on the right pane, it should look like this:

[image: Data Model Inspector]

Delete rules are the the second option from the bottom.

Comment: you are so awesome - 7 minutes from now, you'll be the BEST answer - thank you, thank you, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have to open the Core Data Model file in XCode, select your relationship (obviously attributes don't have delete rules), go to the 3rd tab in the inspector panel on the right and choose your delete rule:

[image]